# Do not write line that begins with certain string

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to omit writing the lines that begin with "KO", however when I run the code the lines still are written to the output file. I tried calling a a boolean expression to see if "KO" was in geneData and it comes back as true. I'm stuck with just that part.

```
#Read in hsa links
hsa = []
with open ('/users/skylake/desktop/pathway-HSAs.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip()
        hsa.append(line)

#Import Modules | Create KEGG Variable
from bioservices.kegg import KEGG
import re
k = KEGG()


##Data Parsing | Writing to File

#for i in range(len(hsa)):
data = k.get(hsa[2])
dict_data = k.parse(data)

#Prep title of file
nameData = re.sub("\[u'", "", str(dict_data['NAME']))
nameData = re.sub(" - Homo sapiens(human)']", "", nameData)
f = open('/Users/Skylake/Desktop/pathway-info/' + nameData + '.txt' , 'w')

#Prep gene data format
geneData = re.sub("', u'", "',\n", str(dict_data['GENE']))
geneData = re.sub("': u'", ": ", geneData)
geneData = re.sub("{u'", "", geneData)
geneData = re.sub("'}", "", geneData)
geneData = re.sub("\[KO", "\nKO", geneData)
f.write("Genes\n")
f.writelines([line for line in geneData if 'KO' not in line])


#Prep compound data format
if 'COMPOUND' in dict_data:
    compData = re.sub("\"", "'", str(dict_data['COMPOUND']))
    compData = re.sub("', u'", "\n", compData)
    compData = re.sub("': u'", ": ", compData)
    compData = re.sub("{u'", "", compData)
    compData = re.sub("'}", "", compData)
    f.write("\nCompounds\n")
    f.write(compData)

#Close file

f.close()
```

Comment: I don't think `if not in` works like that on strings.. Might have to split and iterate but can't be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `genedata` variable is a single string.  When you iterate over it, you are dealing with the individual characters of the string; your `line` variable is horribly misnamed.  The two-character string 'KO' is obviously not contained within any of these single characters, thus your boolean condition is always True.

With no example input data, nor any expected output data, I can't tell what you're trying to do well enough to suggest a solution.